# Constructing a question from the data gathered for the statistical cycle

Tags: soft-question, graphing-functions, descriptive-statistics

**P P D A C** is the statistical cylce that I have to use

**P** stands for **Problem**
**P** stand for **Plan**
**D** stands for **data**
**A** stands for **analysis**
**C** stands for c**onclusion**

I have gathered data on the width and length of a book as well as writing down the title of the 30 books. I have to do this for my internal assesement

I was just wondering what my question should be to start this statistical investigation.

'I wonder if...'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're working out of order (data before the two p's). Here's a catchy question you can answer from your data: "It's often said that the golden ratio ($\approx 1.618$) is the most aesthetically pleasing. What is the mean aspect ratio of books and is it significantly different from the golden ratio?"